# Objects Accessing Variables of Container Class - C++

Tags: c++, variables, object, sharing

How can an object access a variable belonging the class containing it?
Right now I have a class called system that contains some other objects, and those objects need to access and modify one of the variables in the System class.

Example:

```
Class System {
BlockA _blockA = new BlockA();
BlockB _blockB = new BlockB();
BlockC _blockC = new BlockC();
BlockD _blockD = new BlockD();
int myVariable;

...stuff...
}

Class BlockA {
...stuff...
void someFunction () {
System.myVariable++;
}
...stuff...
}

etc...
```

Comment: This is definitely not C++.

Comment: I assume you're a Java programmer using C#. In C#, there are no member classes - a nested class behaves like a nested `static class` in Java. They cannot access the outer variables because they are not instances.

Comment: I wasn't saying this is proper C++.  My question was simply how to achieve the functionality I listed above.  I have a class which contains objects, and those objects need access to one of the variables in the class instantiating them.  A simple that can't be done would have been fine, but I would appreciate if someone could explain what are my alternatives.  My code is highly dependent on this variable to keep things in sync.

Comment: You should read an introductory book on C++ before bothering us with such questions!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I thought about this some more and realized that when initializing the objects, I will pass a pointer to the variable of interest.  That way all objects can read that variable.  For anyone else with this problem, if you need to write, you'll have to make sure that the variable is atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what you're after, but appears something along these lines:

```
#BlockA.h
#ifndef BLOCKA_H
#define BLOCKA_H

class System;

class BlockA {
    System* sys;

public:
    BlockA(System* sys) : sys(sys) {}

    void SomeFunction();
};

#endif // BLOCKA_H
```

---

```
#BlockA.cpp
#include "System.h"

void BlockA::SomeFunction() {
    sys->setMyVariable(sys->getMyVariable() + 1);
}
```

---

```
#System.h
#ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H

class BlockA;

class System {
    BlockA* _blockA;

    int myVariable;

public:
    System();

    int getMyVariable() const;
    void setMyVariable(int value);
    BlockA& getBlockA() const;
};

#endif // SYSTEM_H
```

---

```
#System.cpp
#include "System.h"
#include "BlockA.h"

System::System()
    : _blockA(new BlockA(this)) { }

int System::getMyVariable() const {
    return myVariable;
}

void System::setMyVariable(int value) {
    myVariable = value;
}

BlockA& System::getBlockA() const {
    return *_blockA;
}
```